# Xcode 4: How to set the "continue program execution" key binding?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Hopefully an easy question:

I want to set the key binding for "Continue program execution" in Xcode 4 / iOS SDK 4.3.
Opening the preferences I see every other possibility: Run, Build, Step in, Step out etc. etc.
but "continue program execution" is not there (or any comparable command).

Did the designers screw up or am I missing something ? Neither googling nor stackoverflow helped to find a solution

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to bind with Pause.
It works as Pause\Continue.
Default key binding is ⌃(control) ⌘ (command) Y.

Comment: In fact it does. So easy but the preferences gave no hint